# PHP (md5) empty result

Tags: php, md5

I have a problem with this code sample, the result is a blank page. I checked mcrypt_ecb function in php, and is available. Then why I got only empty result?

```
$suma='9990'; 
$idobj='38'; 
$cislooz='TEST';

$input=$suma.$idobj.$cislooz; 
$key='KEY';

$encrypted_text = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, substr(sha1($input),0,8), MCRYPT_ENCRYPT,substr(sha1($input),0,8)); 

echo "<b>INPUT: </b>".$input."<br>"; 
echo "<b>KEY: </b>".$key."<br>"; 
echo "<b>Hash sha1: </b>".substr(sha1($input),0,8)."<br>"; 
echo "<b>Hash to 3DES/ECB/NoPadding:</b> ".( $encrypted_text )."<br>"; 
echo "<b>to HEX:</b> ".StrToUpper(bin2hex($encrypted_text))."<hr>"; 

?>
```

Comment: What about enabling error reporting?

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of the script to display all errors, warnings etc. Developer debugging 101...

Comment: Depending on your setup, you may also need ini_set('display_errors',1)

Comment: Tried but all I get is a blank page.

Comment: mcrypt_ecb is deprecated. Use mcrypt_generic

Comment: Also, unless you really know what you're doing, don't use ECB. You'd rather use CBC than ECB any day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably experiencing a problem somewhere. I tested it on PHP 5.3.0 and it output:

```
INPUT: 999038TEST
KEY: KEY
Hash sha1: c063a3be
Hash to 3DES/ECB/NoPadding: K\Aj¥íµÉ
to HEX: 4B5C416AA5EDB5C9
```

You may have a PHP error triggered but the only way to know that is to set:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

At the top of your script so that you'll be able to see what the error is.

Another explain is that you started an output buffer with `ob_start()` and you might be managing it wrong.

Or you could have an `exit;` or `die();` somewhere.

As you can see there might be a lot of "because" for your question.

**Edit**:
Finally, at last we discovered the real problem. The spaces in his code where converted to the wrong invisible character; that's because it was copied from a PDF.

[image: no desc]

Here you can see: the first lines works fine and the space correspond to `.` in the script. The other symbol instead (of the commented green lines) was causing the problem.

Comment: mcrypt support enabled, supported modes: ecb

Comment: I am trying, the result is the same: http://d.pr/4Eu3+ and the test page: http://bit.ly/AaVaaI

Comment: Funny, still blank page. Hard thing. It is possible to convert mcrypt_ecb to mcrypt_generic?

Comment: @Adrian, I'll find it out. Wait few minutes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7641/discussion-between-jeff-pigarelli-and-adrian)

Comment: Thank you very much! Disclaimer: newer copy code from PDF. :)